# logical query on mixed (character and numeral) variable

Tags: string, r, list, dataframe, coercion

I didn't think this would be so difficult but I've struggled for some time... I hope it's something simple I am missing :)
I need to be able to logically query a dataframe containing variables that are a mixture of character strings and numerals.

```
LAMBDA<-data.frame(cbind(list(1,"lequiv"),list("lequiv",0)))
LAMBDA!=1
```

What is the best way to achieve this, so that the character strings, which clearly do not equal 1, are reported as FALSE, rather than NA?
Thanks.

Comment: A side note: I would get out of the habit of creating data frames via `data.frame(cbind())`. It's a terrible idiom that frequently does not do what you intended.

Comment: Can you explain why Joran, and if there is an equally succinct approach?  In this case it's actually an argument for another function, so succinct is particularly useful :)

Comment: Well, everything about this is extremely unusual. Data frames _can_ hold lists as "columns" but it is generally frowned upon, since many, many functions that accept data frames will implicitly assume columns of a single type. So if you really _have_ to have a data frame with list columns (and I highly doubt that you do) then this is probably an ok way to create one; but this idiom should should never be used in any other circumstance at all.

Comment: ok sure.  In this case it's the easiest / most efficient way I can see for the user of the package to input data, and I just have to deal with a few hassles pulling it apart.

Comment: Why force it to be a data frame? Data frames are just special cases of lists. It would be more transparent, and easier for users to understand, if you simply used a list of lists.

Comment: ideally it's a matrix with a few character strings that I can pull out.  The user is specifying a series of matrices(to be used in matrix calculations), and some additional constraints.  Rather than force them to specify a value matrix and a mostly/entirely empty constraint(label) matrix, they specify a single matrix-like structure and a list of values for any included constraints(character strings).

Comment: Your last comment makes almost no sense to me at all. Certainly nothing in it even remotely supports shoehorning this into a data frame when lists would suffice.

Comment: the matrix like structure is critical to interpretability.  The alternative option, a genuine matrix and a matching dataframe of mostly NA's with a few character strings, may end up being preferable for clarity even though it's more onerous to specify.  (tried to move this to chat but it wouldn't let me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of testing for elements which are equal to the number 1, you could try testing for elements which are equal to the string "1".  For example:

```
> LAMBDA!="1"
        X1   X2
[1,] FALSE TRUE
[2,]  TRUE TRUE
```

whereas:

```
> LAMBDA!=1
        X1   X2
[1,] FALSE   NA
[2,]    NA TRUE
```

In the first case, R is clever enough to coerce the value 1 in your data frame to be a string before testing for equivalence.  In the second case it cannot coerce "lequiv" to a number betore testing for equivalence and therefore returns NA (and a warning message).

Comment: I like this answer for its simplicity, but I wonder if there is a more explicit way to implement the logic --- my first impression was to test if the elements were numeric (or not a character), but this method doesn't work b/c `class()` returns "list". The classes within the list are revealed in `str()`, though.

Comment: I don't think it is particularly helpful to attribute vague "clever"-ness to R. It would be better to discuss how the Ops class of functions gets dispatched and what sort of coercion is done.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for factors here.

If you look at `str(LAMBDA)` you'll see that `X1` is a list with two elements, one stored as numeric, one as character.

If you instead create your list as follows:

```
l1 <- data.frame(X1=c(1,"lequiv"),
                 X2=c("lequiv",2)
                  )
```

it will look just the same when printed, but the variables are represented as factors.

Then `l1==1` gives:

```
        X1    X2
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Mmmm... it would be nice to have the operation perform directly as expected, but am I right in assuming that other issues are introduced in having a long list of continuous numerals (i.e definitely not separate levels of a factor) interpreted as levels? Or is it only a problem in the event that I wanted to use factors elsewhere in my data structure?

Comment: Not sure I understand - are you trying to store a `list` as an item in a `data.frame`? Can be done - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321786/best-way-to-store-variable-length-data-in-an-r-data-frame) but of course you can't coerce `list` to `double` to use the `==` operator. Glad you found something that worked.